# Hibernate SessionFactory not constructed (-- forced to go with configuration)

Tags: java, hibernate

I was forced to go with an old version of configuration code since the newest had a problem with classpath (I suppose) to detect hibernate.cfg.xml

I developed a tutorial of Hibernate with two entities (Person and Phone, with a join table tblperson_phones). What I have tried is to "actualize" the boot method but at the execution it complains with indicating that the hibernate.cfg.xml file was not found. (I tried also with persistence.xml but no success)
Thus I went to the classic version of buildSessionFactory with Configuration an. This time the hibernate cfg xml file was found but it went into an error at buildSessionFactory.

```
public class PersonManagerBasic {

public org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger;

public List<Person> list_persons;

public PersonManagerBasic() {
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersonManagerBasic.class);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PersonManagerBasic mgr = new PersonManagerBasic();

    //if (args[0].equals("list")) {
    
        mgr.list_persons=mgr.listAllPersons();

        Iterator<Person> it=mgr.list_persons.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Person personex = it.next();
            System.out.println(personex.getName());
        }
    //}
    // get the singleton of sessionFactory to close it
    HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    mgr.logger.log(Level.ERROR, "LoggerName :: "+mgr.logger.getName()+":: program successfully executed");

}

// returns all entities from table "tblpersons"
public List<Person> listAllPersons() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Person> listresult = session.createQuery("from Person p").list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return listresult;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.